# How to travse a linked list in my postcodition use across loop in Eiffel?

Tags: linked-list, eiffel, post-conditions

I try to use 
across 1|..|list.count as j
all
 list.i_th(z) ~ old list.i_th(z)
end

but it says unknown identifier z. Whats wrong with this syntax??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is correct. However, no identifier of name `z` is declared, hence the error. There is a cursor variable `j` instead. The items at the current cursor position are accessed with `j.item`.

Another issue is that `j` is evaluated in the current context (the postcondition), but old expressions are evaluated before the feature body is executed, where `j` is absent. As a result the code with `old list.i_th (j.item)` would not compile. In other words, the value should be taken from the old list but with the current index. The expression `(old list).i_th (j.item)` does the trick.

But this still does not do what is needed. It turns out that `old list = list` because the reference to the list object remains the same. To get the old elements, the copy of the list is required instead: `(old list.twin)`.

Combining all the above, the expression should look like `across 1 |..| list.count as j all list.i_th (j.item) ~ (old list.twin).i_th (j.item) end`.

Comment: It does not work. Either z or j is just a random name for a pointer. It still shows unknown identifier

Comment: Indeed, I missed the fact that there are old expressions. I've corrected the answer to address this issue.